# How to assign value to key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

A few months ago I tried to reassign some keys on my keyboard and accidentally broke my '8' key. Unfortunately, I have no idea how I did it because I tried out a few different methods and didn't notice that I had broken it until a few days later.

To fix it, I used xev to find out the keycode, 17, then I used xmodmap to assign the correct value: `xmodmap -e "keycode 17=8"`.

However, the key still doesn't work. When I check it out in xev it shows the right keycode and the right assigned value but the computer doesn't seem to be recognising when the key is pressed. 
I know the key works because if I hold it down it starts printing 8s after a few seconds.

Update: I just noticed that after messing around with xmodmaps the shift+8 and alt+8 functionality is now also broken so I cannot get a left parenthesis or the left square bracket.

Resetting the keyboard to the default should work. I tried doing it with `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but I am using a lenovo t460p and they don't seem to have correct keyboard model.

I have been looking around the forums but I can't seem to find a solution. The all seem to be for adding shortcuts or switching key values.   Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To reset it: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`

Comment: I'm afraid that had no effect @GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: Well, then you'd better explain *how* you reassigned some keys.

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't know. As I said, I tried out a few different methods for a different key (unsuccessfully) I didn't realise it had happened until a few days later, and that was a few months ago. 
Is there some way I can check if the OS is recognising the key is being pushed?
There must be a config file somewhere that assigns the actions for different keys, right?

Comment: There is not one single file, it's pretty complex, and I for one am not able to help if you don't remember what you did. Possibly a reinstall of the OS is the easiest way to move forward.

Comment: New keyboards are about 20 bucks.

Comment: Which would lose me 20 bucks and gain me a lovely, new keyboard with a broken 8 key, because it was clearly not a problem with the keyboard. 
But thanks for the comment; super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the shortcut I had previously been trying to add via System Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Custom Shortcuts was still there and was the cause of the problem. 
I had been trying to assign the period "." to the "," key on the German numeric keypad on my keyboard. I added the shortcut via the GUI and I'm not sure how it got mixed up. The '8' key did not seem to be assigned to it. 
When I tried `xmodmap -pke | grep 8`, the key seemed to be assigned correctly. Also, resetting the keyboard with `setxkbmap -layout de` had no effect. 
However, when I deleted the shortcut the 8 key went back to behaving normally.